# Is it possible for me to model mathematically the revolution to sharpen a pencil using complex number?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, regression, piecewise-continuity, eulers-method

I was planning to do research on complex number since I find the topic intriguing, How can I conduct a research by modelling mathematically to calculate the required number of rotation for a pencil in a circular motion when sharpening the pencil with a sharpener using complex number by linking the number of rotations, length of graphite and the time taken?

Comment: I've sharpened pencils any number of times, using various tools... but never complex numbers. Maybe it's worth a try. ;-)

Comment: Why do you think complex numbers are useful to sharpen pencils?

Comment: @DonAntonio The reason why I think complex numbers are useful to sharpen pencils because there's rotation when sharpening pencils and I think I can also relate to trigonometry as well so can I see the possibilities of using complex numbers but I'm not sure how can I use it.

Comment: @NoNames yeah, I'm still learning about complex numbers and somehow I wanna give complex numbers a try because I think it's possible to use it in this real-life application.